# How to get tls from homebrew's tcl-tk package?

Tags: macos, ssl, tcl

I'm on [macOS Mojave](https://www.apple.com/macos/mojave/), which has tcl but is version 8.5:

```
$ /usr/bin/tclsh
% puts $tcl_version
8.5
```

I'd like to use version 8.6, so I installed from [homebrew](https://brew.sh), but unfortunately, it does not have the `tls` package which is needed for downloading via https:

```
$ /usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/bin/tclsh
% puts $tcl_version
8.6
% package require tls
can't find package tls
```

How do I get the tcl 8.6 *and* the `tls` package on Mac?

Comment: Are we to assume you have ruled out just downloading the sources and building it?

Answer (score 0):

Once you installed `Homebrew`, just do:

```
brew tap caskroom/cask
brew cask install tcl
```

---

Brew setup your path automatically, so you don't need to do anything else:

Checking path:

```
$ which tclsh
/usr/local/bin/tclsh
$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/tclsh
/usr/local/bin/tclsh@ -> /Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.6/bin/tclsh
```

Checking version:

```
$ tclsh
% puts $tcl_version
8.6
exit
```

Comment: The cask version of tcl is ActiveTcl and I would prefer to use the plain, official version. My question is to how to get tls to work with the homebrew version of tcl, not what is another distribution of tcl that has tls included.

Comment: Well, I don't know whether `brew install tcl` is any more "official" than `brew cask install tcl`. Anything taken from ActiveTcl might not track the latest and greatest of Tcl, though (8.6.8 vs. 8.6.9). You might want to go to http://kitcreator.rkeene.org/kitcreator, build a tclkit ,with the "TclTLS" checkbox ticked, for your platform (macOS amd64) and fetch the tcltls extension from therein? But this requires you to unpack the tclkit ([`sdx unwrap`](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/sdx)). Alternatively, you may want to just build TclTLS from scratch, as andy is hinting at?

Comment: @mrcalvin Yes, it would be "more official", because [Homebrew's tcl-tk](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/tcl-tk.rb) compiles from the official source bundle. I suppose my alternative is to just compile from source.

Comment: which tcltls version do you want?